# Updating dictionary elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the key as a string and list of length 6 as values. the list is composed of a dictionary with the key as a string and it's respective value for e.g.

```
{ 'conv_01': [{'high': 0},
  {'low': 16},
  {'cummulative': 121.41315},
  {'min': -3.2385397},
  {'max': 46.390823364257813},
  {'pos': 1}] }
```

What will be the most efficient way to update this dictionary element. For e.g. if I want to update pos as **18**.

```
{'conv_01': [{'high': 0},
  {'low': 16},
  {'cummulative': 121.41315},
  {'min': -3.2385397},
  {'max': 46.390823364257813},
  {'pos': 18}] } # Expected output
```

The overall size of the root dictionary is big, thus efficiency is important.

UPADTE w.r.t. comments

1. The order of the list is always same i.e.pos will always be at 6th place.
2. Why am I using this structure i.e. dict{ [ dict{k,v}, dict2{k,v} ] }? I was given data this way. Although, I will definitely try to suggest to remove the list and just use dict.

Comment: `d['conv_01'][0]['pos'] = 18` ?

Comment: Most efficient in what terms? CPU cycles, memory, code readability? And are `pos` and `18` values *variables*?

Comment: @falsetru: `-1`, not `0`, surely?

Comment: In terms of CPU cycles. pos is not a variable but 18 is. @falsetru I am using the same code, but want to know if there exists anything better than this in terms of CPU cycles.

Comment: The structure you have does not to be very efficient to begin with. Why do you need the list of dicts and not simply a dict? like `{'conv_01': {'high': 0, 'low': 16, ...}}`? A dict of 1 pair loses its purpose imho

Comment: @blackbug: so is the list always in the same order? If `pos` is always the last dictionary (or the 6th), then ujust use a fixed position, like `falsetru` showed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Oops.

Comment: And please do update your question with the clarifications we ask for in comments. That way the comments can be removed safely without affecting your question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But if we always have the same order we don't need the inner dictionaries. I think this is just a case of "I created a monster and I don't know why."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the position of the given key is constant, just use that directly:

```
new_value = 18
d['conv_01'][-1]['pos'] = new_value  # last entry
d['conv_01'][5]['pos'] = new_value   # 6th entry
```

If the key is variable or the order of the entries is unknown, you'll need to execute a search. Use a list comprehension to just re-build the list:

```
key, new_value = 'pos', 18
d['conv_01'] = [{key: new_value} if key in d else d for d in d['conv_01']]
```

However, if you need to repeatedly make such changes, it'd be *much more efficient* to convert your list of dictionaries to one dictionary up front, then just use the key directly:

```
d['conv_01'] = dict(next(iter(d.items())) for d in d['conv_01'])
d['conv_01][key] = new_value
```

This assumes that all your keys in your nested dictionaries are unique, of course.